Neural network Logic Errors
I was working on a neural network project that uses this dataset; https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/320/student+performance.
The data has two main types of data. It has binaries (0 or 1) and numerical value options (eg. 1,2,3,4). In my neural network, I converted the data to either the binaries (from yes / no) and the numerical values to between 0 and 1 using a normalization function. The Network has 32 inputs, 1 Hidden Layer, 22 hidden nodes in that layer and one output.
The network has an issue where going through the data and training, it produces ridiculous values where w2 weights are to the 10^50 power.
Does anyone have any advice on this?
I can provide additional details as well if you'd like.
Thank you!

training neural networks is hard. It's probably going to be easiest for you to do this if you start with a neural net which is already doing regression on some other dataset well, and then plug in your dataset. Without more details, it's hard to say what's going wrong. Have you standardized your data? Have you tried a smaller learning rate? What activation functions are you using? What framework have you implemented your neural net in?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The key clue is weights that are on the order of $10^{50}$; this is a classic case of exploding gradients or, less likely, overshooting. There's a comprehensive debugging procedure in the duplicate.

It would have been better to look at a sample code of this neural network, or preciser said, at the way you implemented it. A good dataset only gets you so far and then the optimizations lie more in the way you program it. These optimzations can be anywhere from pythonic optimzations such as vectorization to logic-level optmization such as inherent flaws of the followed processes which may need to be solved.
From what I may deduce is that you may have an exploding gradients problem, wherein depending on the batch size, when the gradients are computed over the course of epochs, they start increasing, and even exponentiating. The first and foremost step (assuming the data is clean with the absence of invalid NaN values), would be to clip the gradients upto 1. This alone is not the end solution to the problem since now it may cause vanishing gradients. But as a start, this may help. And @John Madden's questions are pretty valid as well.
